# Rails JSON not Working in JS Function

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json

I'm trying to get a json response from a rails controller and insert it into a js function. I keep getting errors:

MY CONTROLLER

```
def live #users present or attendees view
    @presentation = Presentation.find(params[:secret])
    @countdown = @presentation.start - DateTime.now()


    #IF A PERSON IS A PRESENTER
    if @presentation.presenter.id == current_user.id
      @presenter = true
      require 'json'
      require 'net/http'
      require 'uri'

      uri = URI.parse('https://api.screenleap.com/v2/screen-shares')
      req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path, initheader = {'accountid' => 'APPID', 'authtoken' => 'MYTOKEN'}) #These are correct in actual code
      http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
      http.use_ssl = true
      res = http.request(req)

      @screenShareData = JSON.parse(res.body)

    #IF A PERSON IS AN ATTENDEE
    else
      @presenter = false
      @screenShareData = false
    end
  end
```

IN MY VIEW

```
<script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://api.screenleap.com/js/screenleap.js"></script>

  window.onload = function() {
    var callbacks = {
      nativeDownloadStarting: [onNativeDownloadStartCallback],
      screenShareStarting: [onScreenShareStarting],
      appConnectionFailed: [onAppConnectionFailed],
      screenShareStartError: [onScreenShareStartError]
    };
    var screenShareData = <%= @screenShareData %>;
    var presenterAppType = 'NATIVE';

    screenleap.startSharing(presenterAppType, screenShareData, callbacks);
  };
</script>
```

In my view I also tried:

```
var screenShareData = <%= @screenShareData.to_s.html_safe %>;
```

In either case I seem to get one of two javascript errors. Either "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &" or "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>"

My feeling is that it's somehow not translating the JSON the way the function expects it. Any idea how I might fix the issue?

Comment: isn't `@screenShareData = JSON.parse(res.body)` parsing the JSON data and storing as Hash? Either you do not parse it at all or convert it to JSON using `.to_json` method.

Comment: my feeling is that you're not getting a `json` response from your controller, try `console.log(screenSharedData)` to see what you got.

Comment: take a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6404950/how-do-you-output-json-from-ruby-on-rails

Comment: I tried not parsing it as well. To no avail. Also I am getting a json response because I can display it and all the data in the view as a string. I'll take a look at the question you linked, Taki, I think that is similar to the response below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the rails JSON variable I got from the controller by modifying the variable in the view as below:

```
<%= @screenShareData.to_json.html_safe %>
```

After that, the screenleap.startSharing function accepted the data and worked. It should be noted that I also removed the "callbacks" variable, but I isolated the change in the "screenShareData" variable as the one that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `irb` syntax in js code

```
var screenShareData = <%= @screenShareData %>;
```

There are a few options to achieve what you want:

1. respond with json in your controller action and request it from client via ajax request
2. render this data `@screenShareData` in any of html tags data-attribute and get it with jQuery or vanilla js methods

**UPDATE**: I was wrong about that and you can inject ruby code in js. Here is an answer to your question:

```
var screenShareData = JSON.parse("<%= j @screenShareData.to_json.html_safe %>")
```

Where [j is an alias to escape_javascript](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper/escape_javascript).

There is also another way:

```
var screenShareData = <%= raw @screenShareData.to_json.html_safe %>
```

But I would not suggest that because:

1. It might not work in some cases. If for example `@screenShareData`
   has special characters and such
2. `@screenShareData` might have some code inside that will be executed in client browser

---

Also I suggest you to move `api.screenleap.com` request logic from controller action to service object.

What are you going to do if `api.screenleap.com` is unavailable or responds with an error?

`Net::HTTP::Post` is a blocking request means that if `api.screenleap.com` takes 5 seconds to respond then your client browser render will hold for 5 seconds. I suggest you do it async unless its desired behavior

You have different data formats in the same action response. If `@presentation.presenter.id == current_user.id` is `true` then its an array or an object. If `false` then its boolean. That's not cool

Comment: Thanks I'll give this a shot. Stay tuned... As for the messy formats, I haven't built out the situation where someone is accessing the page but not a presenter. So everything in the "else" is just a placeholder to avoid an "undefined variable" error, when I start to build it. It will not be its final form. Thanks again for your advice.

Comment: Your first statement is incorrect.  You can use ERB in JS code.

Comment: @RyanFriedman thanks for pointing that out. I updated my answer